# How to find dimensions for Material Design UI Elements?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-xml

When trying to pick padding and width and margin for UI elements, I see that some default values pop up in the XML. This makes me think --> Is there a standard set of measurements that I can use for material design instead of trying to guess what looks right?

Like in the picture below, where specifically in the documentation can i find the list of all dimensions available?

[image]

Comment: i got confused between my projects. i have those in my dimens.xml file. I found them here. http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs

Answer (score 0):

Android specifies certain widths and heights that you should use for your application. For example the horizontal and vertical activity margins, the padding in `TextView` or `EditText`. See https://material.google.com/layout/metrics-keylines.html for the guidelines.

Comment: that's what confuses me. Is there a way I am supposed to calculate the `dp` values from that link?

Comment: I usually define all the values in the dimen xml file because I am still running Eclipse. When there is a change in the guideline I change the values in the xml file